# List FormatConditions of all controls on an Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to list the conditional formatting of all controls on a form?  I'd like to be able to list out all existing conditions so that I can generate code to add/remove the existing conditions.  I have inherited some complex forms and want to know what I'm dealing with and then generate some code to toggle the conditional formatting in areas where it is slowing down navigating a continuous form.

This Excel VBA example shows a similar format I'd like to have for Access.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204597/1898524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some inspiration from @June7's example and some code from an [article](https://vb123.com/listing-conditional-formats/) I found by Garry Robinson, I wrote a procedure that answers my question.

Here's the output in the Immediate window.  This is ready to be pasted into a module.  The design time property values are shown as a comment.

```
txtRowColor.FormatConditions.Delete
txtRowColor.FormatConditions.Add acExpression, acBetween, "[txtCurrent_Equipment_List_ID]=[txtEquipment_List_ID]"
With txtRowColor.FormatConditions.Item(txtRowColor.FormatConditions.Count-1)
    .Enabled          = True           ' txtRowColor.Enabled=False
    .ForeColor        = 0              ' txtRowColor.ForeColor=-2147483640
    .BackColor        = 10092543       ' txtRowColor.BackColor=11850710
End With
```

You can test this sub from a click event on an open form.  I was getting some false positives when checking the Boolean `.Enabled` property, even when I store the values into Boolean variables first.  I don't know why and am researching it, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

```
Public Sub ListConditionalFormats(frmForm As Form)
' Show all the Textbox and Combobox controls on the passed form object (assuming the form is open).
' Output the FormatCondtion properties to the immediate window in a format that is
' suitable to be copied into VBA to recreate the conditional formatting.
' The design property value is shown as a comment on each condition property row.
    Dim ctl             As Control
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim bolControlEnabled As Boolean
    Dim bolFormatEnabled As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    For Each ctl In frmForm.Controls

        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
            With ctl
                If .FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
                    'Debug.Print vbCr & "' " & ctl.Name, "Count = " & .FormatConditions.Count
                    For i = 0 To .FormatConditions.Count - 1

                        ' Generate code that can recreate each FormatCondition
                        Debug.Print ctl.Name & ".FormatConditions.Delete"
                        Debug.Print ctl.Name & ".FormatConditions.Add " & DecodeType(.FormatConditions(i).Type) _
                                    & ", " & DecodeOp(.FormatConditions(i).Operator) _
                                    & ", """ & Replace(.FormatConditions(i).Expression1, """", """""") & """" _
                                    & IIf(Len(.FormatConditions(i).Expression2) > 0, ", " & .FormatConditions(i).Expression2, "")
                        Debug.Print "With " & ctl.Name & ".FormatConditions.Item(" & ctl.Name & ".FormatConditions.Count-1)"

                        bolControlEnabled = ctl.Enabled
                        bolFormatEnabled = .FormatConditions(i).Enabled
                        'Debug.Print bolControlEnabled <> bolFormatEnabled, bolControlEnabled, bolFormatEnabled
                        If bolControlEnabled <> bolFormatEnabled Then    ' <- This sometimes fails.  BS 2/9/2020
                            'If ctl.Enabled <> .FormatConditions(i).Enabled Then ' <- This sometimes fails.  BS 2/9/2020
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".Enabled          = " & .FormatConditions(i).Enabled; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".Enabled=" & ctl.Enabled
                        End If

                        If ctl.ForeColor <> .FormatConditions(i).ForeColor Then
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".ForeColor        = " & .FormatConditions(i).ForeColor; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".ForeColor=" & ctl.ForeColor
                        End If
                        If ctl.BackColor <> .FormatConditions(i).BackColor Then
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".BackColor        = " & .FormatConditions(i).BackColor; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".BackColor=" & ctl.BackColor
                        End If
                        If ctl.FontBold <> .FormatConditions(i).FontBold Then
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".FontBold         = " & .FormatConditions(i).FontBold; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".FontBold=" & ctl.FontBold
                        End If
                        If ctl.FontItalic <> .FormatConditions(i).FontItalic Then
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".FontItalic       = " & .FormatConditions(i).FontItalic; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".FontItalic=" & ctl.FontItalic
                        End If
                        If ctl.FontUnderline <> .FormatConditions(i).FontUnderline Then
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".FontUnderline    = " & .FormatConditions(i).FontUnderline; Tab(40); "' " & ctl.Name & ".FontUnderline=" & ctl.FontUnderline
                        End If

                        If .FormatConditions(i).Type = 3 Then    ' acDataBar
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".LongestBarLimit  = " & .FormatConditions(i).LongestBarLimit
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".LongestBarValue  = " & .FormatConditions(i).LongestBarValue
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".ShortestBarLimit = " & .FormatConditions(i).ShortestBarLimit
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".ShortestBarValue = " & .FormatConditions(i).ShortestBarValue
                            Debug.Print vbTab & ".ShowBarOnly      = " & .FormatConditions(i).ShowBarOnly
                        End If
                        Debug.Print "End With" & vbCr
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Beep

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "in procedure ListConditionalFormats" _
        & IIf(Erl > 0, vbCrLf & "Line #: " & Erl, "")
    GoTo Exit_Sub
    Resume Next
    Resume
End Sub

Function DecodeType(TypeProp As Integer) As String
' You heed this are there are 4 different ways to setup a CondtionalFormat
' https://vb123.com/listing-conditional-formats

    Select Case TypeProp
        Case 0
            DecodeType = "acFieldValue"
        Case 1
            DecodeType = "acExpression"
        Case 2
            DecodeType = "acFieldHasFocus"
        Case 3
            DecodeType = "acDataBar"
    End Select

End Function

Function DecodeOp(OpProp As Integer) As String
' You need this becuase equations can comprise of = > <> between
' https://vb123.com/listing-conditional-formats

    Select Case OpProp
        Case 0
            DecodeOp = "acBetween"
        Case 1
            DecodeOp = "acNotBetween"
        Case 2
            DecodeOp = "acEqual"
        Case 3
            DecodeOp = "acNotEqual"
        Case 4
            DecodeOp = "acGreaterThan"
        Case 5
            DecodeOp = "acLessThan"
        Case 6
            DecodeOp = "acGreaterThanOrEqual"
        Case 7
            DecodeOp = "acLessThanOrEqual"
    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Only textboxes and comboboxes have Conditional Formatting.

There is no single property that can be listed to show a control's conditional formatting rule(s). Each rule has attributes that can be listed. Example of listing for a single specific control:

```
Private Sub Command25_Click()
Dim x As Integer
With Me.tbxRate
For x = 0 To .FormatConditions.Count - 1
    Debug.Print .FormatConditions(x).BackColor
    Debug.Print .FormatConditions(x).Expression1
    Debug.Print .FormatConditions(x).FontBold
Next
End With
End Sub
```

The output for this example:

```
 2366701 
20
False
```

These are attributes for a rule that sets backcolor to red when field value is greater than 20.

Yes, code can loop through controls on form, test for textbox and combobox types, determine if there are CF rules and output attributes.