# Validate conditional formatting using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation, icons, conditional-formatting

I am writing a VBA code to validate conditional formatting for Icon Sets value. Another team did the Icon Set conditional formatting using conditional formatting option in excel. I want to use VBA to ensure that the Icon Set Value refers to the right cell. The reason I want to do this is because I have multiple rows of conditional formatting and I want to ensure each row refers to the correct Icon Set Value. Therefore, I want to use VBA to check that I am referring to the right cell.

I have constructed the VBA code but I am having challenges figuring out code to validate/check the existing iconset condition, instead of adding icon set condition.

The code "Set iset = rg.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition" add another condition to the excel range and thus the following IF statement check the Icon Set Value for the newly added Icon Set Condition. Not the one that I want to check. I'm unsure of what code should I write that check the existing Icon Set Value not add a new Icon Set Condition.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Attached below is the code that I'm using. Note that the code below is a simplified version where it checks for one range only.

****VBA Code****

```
Sub check_iconset()
    Dim iset As IconSetCondition
    Dim result As String
    Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Range("AG8")

Range("AJ7").Name = "y"
Range("AL7").Name = "x"

Set iset = rg.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition

If iset.IconCriteria(2).Value >= y And iset.IconCriteria(3).Value >= x Then
result = True
Else
result = False
End If

Range("AG9").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889142/print-all-conditional-formatting-rules-for-a-spreadsheet/43531530

Comment: Thank you ! I will have a look at the link you shared. I believe it will be very helpful