# Delete Excel individual format condition

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have an old workbook with Conditional Formatting that has got out of hand in terms of random conditional formatting having evolved.  I would like to loop through the sheet and delete all the conditional formatting that only refers to one cell (but preserve other formatting in the same cell and of course preserve the cell value etc.)

I have written the code in a separate sheet so that (1) I can re-use it and (2) the workbook itself doesn't need macros

[image: Delete Rule with only one Applies to]

So far, I can *identify* the cells but can't delete the formatting.  The code I have is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_Conditional()

Dim fc As FormatCondition
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastCol As Long
Dim rAllCells As Range, rCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Find last cell and set a range to cover all cells
    lLastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rAllCells = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol))
    
    'Loop through all cells
    For Each rCell In rAllCells.Cells
        'Loop through all FormatConditions in the cell
        For Each fc In rCell.FormatConditions
            'Determine if the FormatCondition only applies to one cell
            If fc.AppliesTo.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Debug.Print fc.AppliesTo.Address
                'I have tried fc.Delete
                'I have tried fc.AppliesTo.Delete
                End If
            Next fc
        Next rCell

End Sub
```

When I go back to the sheet, I can see the formatting still exists.

Comment: What happened when you tried (eg) `fc.Delete` ? Did you get an error, or ?  That seemed to work fine for me.  Do you see the debug.print output?

Comment: Have you tried ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

Comment: Try to use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891190/15035314 to get FC
 and then delete them

Comment: @TimWilliams, When I try the `fc.Delete`, I get a _Subscript out of range_ error.  The Debug.Print shows me the AppliesTo.Address.  Having re-run it to answer your question, it appears to be working (I think n-1 times where n is the number of single-cell conditions) then raising an error before all cells can complete

Comment: @mooseman, I think this would delete _all_ the conditions?  I only want to remove the 'orphans' where a conditional format has been copied to a single cell and the condition should apply to a range (e.g. a whole column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting from a collection of items sometimes it works better if you work backwards:

```vb
Sub Delete_Conditional()

Dim fc As FormatCondition
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastCol As Long
Dim rAllCells As Range, rCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook, i As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Find last cell and set a range to cover all cells
    lLastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rAllCells = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol))
    
    'Loop through all cells
    For Each rCell In rAllCells.Cells
        'Loop through all FormatConditions in the cell
        For i = rCell.FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
            With rCell.FormatConditions(i)
                If .AppliesTo.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                    Debug.Print .AppliesTo.Address
                    .Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought that my original code would delete only the condition that it had found to match the criteria but I'm guessing that there was a bump up the 'register' when that happened and the next one 'no longer existed'

Comment: Yep it sometimes "works" with a For Each (and it did for me when testing) but the reverse loop typically fixes this type of intermittent bug.